Salesforce limitation for getting records using an expression
We have B2B commerce implementation. On an LWR site in an experience builder, salesforce has given an option to get cart data using an expression. What we have done is declared an api property in LWC and in xml file we have define below target config to get cart item data using an expression:
<targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
        <property name="cartDetails" type="String" label="Cart Details" default="{!Cart.Details}"/>
        <property name="cartItems" type="String" label="Cart Items" default="{!Cart.Items}"/>
    </targetConfig>
</targetConfigs>

This cart items expression is only fetching 25 records, while on salesforce cart we have more than 200 cart items. Is there any to increase the limit to fetch the cart items using an expression? Or custom apex is the only option here?
Any information related to this will be helpful.
